# Custom radio button w3s example

Tags: css, css-selectors

There is a custom radio buttons example at the w3schools.com:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_radio

I wonder, what's the reason to have separate `.container .checkmark:after` statement? Why these styles are not included directly to `.checkmark:after` statement?

Full code example:

```css
/* The container */
.container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
 left: 9px;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: @Roberrrt: I don't think that's the full code example - only the CSS is present, and the snippet displays nothing as a result.

Comment: That's correct, updating now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real reason why this happens, I suppose w3schools has the following motives:

- The first rule with `.checkmark:after` doesn't really give any markup other than setting the content, position and display. This is merely a preparation for styling, which can be applied to every checkbox on the website without consequences if other styling is being changed.
- In this example, there's only one area that contains styled inputs, but in a large website multiple input fields might be available. It's not a problem to apply an invisible pseudo element (modern browsers don't fully render `display: none` [on page load anyway](http://cssbasics.zemplate.com/css-topics/78-css-topics-does-display-none-alter-page-load-speeds)), but you can control which inputs are actually styled this way.

It's a matter of semantics, separating the actual styling and logic.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example `you can just omit ".container" because the only radio buttons present are also enclosed within the container` class label so the same CSS styling is applied.

**But what if the case is, you want to have different styles applied and the radio buttons are not placed within the same container class?**

If you make use of `"input:checked ~ .checkmark:after"` without mentioning in which container specifically it is present, the styling `would be just applied to all the elements of the type input` and not just the ones inside the container class.